# how to break line ,i am unable to break the line of " cardInfo" inside cardDataInfo array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, split, line, break

[image]
[image]
[image]
I tried using but instead getting error like violation-->

return (

{cardDataInfo.split("\n").map(renderCard)}

```
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to the community, please, do not post code as an image

Answer (score 0):

you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
cardDataInfo.split(/\r?\n|\r|\n/g);
```